# Why boost::condition_variable can use pthread_cond_signal to wake up only one thread

Tags: c++, unix, boost, pthreads

In the source code of boost::condition_variable, method condition_variable::notify_one() try to use pthread_cond_signal() to wake up only one thread.
https://code.woboq.org/appleseed/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp.html

```
inline void condition_variable::notify_one() BOOST_NOEXCEPT
    {
#if defined BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_INTERRUPTIONS
        boost::pthread::pthread_mutex_scoped_lock internal_lock(&internal_mutex);
#endif
        BOOST_VERIFY(!pthread_cond_signal(&cond));
    }
```

However, POSIX says :

> The pthread_cond_signal() function shall unblock at least one of the threads that are blocked on the specified condition variable cond (if any threads are blocked on cond).

So why boost::condition_variable make sure that the pthread_cond_signal just wake up one thread???

Answer (score 0):

> So why boost::condition_variable make sure that the pthread_cond_signal just wake up one thread???

Why? That question is moot. The question is "whether". And it doesn't (as you see).

You can see that it uses the pthread API there to unblock ***at least*** one waiting thread.

This is merely as opposed to `notify_all`, which uses `pthread_cond_broadcast`.

The distinction is useful because it can improve the efficiency of concurrent operations in situations where waking up all waiters would be wasteful.

> Related: when using condition variables, you must always take [spurious wake-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup#:%7E:text=A%20spurious%20wakeup%20happens%20when,been%20awakened%20for%20no%20reason.) into account

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking about the *name* of `boost::condition_variable::notify_one()` in light of the fact that the pthread-based implementation may in fact wake up more than one thread.

The fact is that although the specifications for `pthread_cond_signal()` say that it will unblock "at least one" thread blocked on the CV (provided there are any), that is weaselly standard-speak.  Although it is *allowed* for `pthread_cond_signal()` to unblock more than one thread, it is usual and expected that if any threads are blocked on the CV when it is signaled, then exactly one will be unblocked.  Allowing for more than one to be unblocked allows for implementations to be lighter-weight and more efficient, and it places no new burden on programmers because the same measures that handle *spurious* wakeups should be equally effective against *extra* wakeups, supposing that you even choose to distinguish between those.

Thus, `boost::condition_variable::notify_one()` is so named because "notify_one" accurately represents a behavior that programmers are anticipated sometimes to want, and the so-named method is the way for them to request it.  That occasionally it delivers something a bit different is a characteristic of a very wide variety of functions. It is not helpful to try to capture all the details in the name.  Not only would you end up with unreadably long names, such as `notify_at_least_one_if_any_are_waiting`, but you would lose the sense of the *primary* expectation for the function's behavior.

Comment: So you mean that although the function name is 'notify_one', but actually it may notify more than one threads and its behavior will be same with 'pthread_cond_signal'?

Comment: More or less, @xuhaoee.  There is every reason to think that it will attempt to wake exactly one thread waiting on the CV, but it may not be possible on any given platform for it to *ensure* that no more than one unblocks.  This is a characteristic of many real-world CV implementations, and it is indeed the same behavior as `pthread_cond_signal`.